# Is it possible to have tag suggestion in ctags while searching for a tag?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I am using `exuberent-ctags` with `vim 8.0`. While searching for a tag with a long name, I'd like to have a list of suggestions having the typed string as the sub-string when I use the `:ta` command. What I want is to have a feature like Sublime's `Ctrl+P`, that allows you to search for a symbol. Is it possible to achieve the same with `ctags`?

Comment: You might want to check out the [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) for questions on Vim!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag completion should work out-of-the-box by hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> key. You may also want to set the option `set wildmenu` to prefer to show the results in the popup menu.

Also, make sure to read `:h 'wildmode'` to select the most appropriate menu mode for you (`set wildmode=longest:full`?)

Also read `:h cmdline_completion` to find a few other useful key combinations, such as <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>.